# Elasticsearch: Not analyzing when searching on a particular field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm indexing some data into elasticsearch, one bit of which is an IP address (stored as string type, rather than ip type). I'm using a custom analyzer for the IP address field which is defined as follows:

```
'ipv4_address_analyzer' => [
    'type' => 'custom',
    'tokenizer' => 'ipv4_path_tokenizer',
    'filter' => [],
],
```

The ipv4_path_tokenizer is defined as follows:

```
'ipv4_path_tokenizer' => [
    'type' => 'path_hierarchy',
    'delimiter' => '.',
    'buffer_size' => 15,
],
```

When I use the `index_analyzer` property on the field in the mapping, this is indexed and searched correctly with the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "95.129",
      "fields": [
        "external_ip",
        "domains",
        "_all"
      ],
      "use_dis_max": true
    }
  },
  "size": 1000
}
```

However... the search term is still processed by the default search analyser and this produces a few false positive matches.

I know I can specify a search_analyzer property on the IP field to use a different search analyzer however what I really want is for the search term to be left untouched when searching this field rather than being run through an analyzer.

Is there a way to disable search term analysis on a per field basis?

Comment: Can you give an example of the false positive matches?  I don't understand what you mean by leaving the search term untouched.  Maybe a multi-field would help?  Or putting the IP in a term filter instead of the query string?

Comment: Thanks @kielni. If the search term is analyzed and tokenized on '.' then 12.34.56.78 gets tokenized to (amongst other things) 12, 34, 56, 78. As such, it matches the IP 56.78.90.12 because it's tokenized by the path_hierarchy as 56, 56.78, 56.78.90 and 56.78.90.12. In essence, I don't want to analyze the search term when searching on that field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the answer when cruising the manual. The **keyword** tokenizer leaves the original term in tact, except for truncating it to the maximum buffer size. No filters are required. Custom analyzer below:

```
'leave_me_alone' => [
    'type' => 'custom',
    'tokenizer' => 'keyword',
    'filter' => [],
],
```